# Generate PDF with vector graphics

Tags: asp.net, pdf, vector-graphics

I have an idea where I need to be able to dynamically create a PDF-file thats supposed to contain a number of vector-graphical images.. I also need to be able to "absolute" position the vector images within the PDF.. I then later on need to be able to download the generated PDF-file.. is this possible?..has anyone done something like this before?.. as far as I can remember there is a pretty good support for doing this using none vectorized-images (jpg,png etc).. but is it possible to use eps-files and other vector images?

Comment: If you merely want to create vector graphics in a new or existing PDF, you can do that e.g. with iText(Sharp). If on the other hand want to import existing vector graphics without further ado, that is a different matter altogether.

Comment: yeah well.. I want to be able to import for instance an eps file or svg or some other vectorized-file-type into the PDF.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pdflatex` to generate the pdf.

(pdf)Latex has really good support for importing svg and eps.

When you use Inkscape you can chose to export to tex/latex and it generates code for you.